# github: pulling reverted last commit on master to production

Tags: git

I'm working on a project as follows (providing full context, just in case):

1. Make changes on my local machine, test on `localhost:5000`, etc.
2. `git push` changes to github.
3. ssh into a Linux server and `git pull` the changes down to be served on a running web server.

To keep things simple, let's say we have a fresh repo with nothing but a README in it. Push 2 commits:

#### Commit 1

```
echo "foo" >> README.md
git add -A
git commit -m "Added text 'foo' to README"
git push
```

#### Commit 2

```
echo "bar" >> README.md
git add -A
git commit -m "Added text 'bar' to README"
git push
```

Now, I wish to simply wish to roll back the version that's on Github to the state in *commit 1*, i.e. just "foo", without "bar".

I can do this on local with:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
git push origin +master
```

Which successfully rolls back the **commit 2** on github. When I try to `git pull` this reverted version in my production server, however, I get:

```
Already up-to-date.
```

Which is obviously wrong.

P.S. If anyone has any suggestions on a better dev-on-local/test/push-to-prod workflows than my current one, or any other such github best practices, I'm all ears. Note that I'm the only person working on this project.

Comment: Did you try `git push -f` ?

Answer (score 0):

A correct way of undoing a local commit is to use `git revert <commit_hash>`. This will save you from the hassle of using `git reset`.

Try the following.

```
git revert <hash_of_bar_changes>
git push
ssh <remote>
git pull
```

Answer (score 0):

so in my opinion, it is better to have another branch for each feature. Rather than directly pushing to master. The general workflow I would follow for your example would be

Assume you are on the master branch and the name of the remote is origin

**Commit 1**

```
echo "foo" >> README.md
git checkout -B feature-branch 
git add -A
git commit -m "Added text 'foo' to README"
git push origin feature-branch
```

### After the first commit, there are 2 things you can do depending on the nature of your next commit.

**1. commit 2 is a part of feature branch**

**Commit 2**

```
echo "bar" >> README.md
git add -A
git commit -m "Added text 'bar' to README"
git push origin feature-branch
```

now before you pull from your production server you would have to merge the feature to master branch like below

```
git checkout master
git merge feature-branch
git push origin master
```

or you can submit a [pull request](https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/creating-a-pull-request) on GitHub and merge it on Github

**2. commit 2 is a new feature**

In this case, you would merge the feature-branch to master before adding commit-2's changes. So you would first

```
git checkout master
git merge feature-branch
git push origin master
```

Then you would checkout to a new-feature branch

```
git checkout -B new-feature
echo "bar" >> README.md
git add -A
git commit -m "Added text 'bar' to README"
git push origin new-feature
```

After that you would either submit a Pull request on github and merge it or you can merge it locally and push the changes like so before pulling from the production server.

```
git checkout master
git merge new-feature
git push origin master
```

After that you can pull the master branch on production server.

```
git pull origin master
```

### Now coming to the reverted commit

once you execute the below commands

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
git push origin +master
```

what happens is the repository's state is reset to `commit 1`. According to your production version it is ahead of master by one commit because it already has the commit that master is on (HEAD) and it has one other commit that master does not. Hence it is unable to pull the changes.

A simple workaround this would be to use revert instead of reset

```
git revert "hash of commit 2"
git push origin master
```

because inherently this creates a new commit without the changes of the previous commit. Hence master(github/remote) will be ahead of your production and when you pull the changes will be applied.

When you do reset the `HEAD` (think of something like a pointer) of the master branch is pointing to the previous commit (which means the latest commit is not erased)

Refer

- https://www.pixelstech.net/article/1549115148-git-reset-vs-git-revert
- https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert
- https://gist.github.com/blackfalcon/8428401